# How to transfer WhatsApp from Windows to Android?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, windows-mobile

I have a Lumia 535 and a Samsung S7 Edge. I am unable to transfer my WhatsApp to Android from Lumia. I have WhatsApp backup on OneDrive. Is there any way?

Comment: whatsapp has an option to restore from Google drive backup. Is there any option to backup to google drive in lumia 535?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone uses OneDrive and Android uses Google Drive for backup.Currently, Whatsapp does not support inter cloud backup transfer. You can subscribe to [this Reddit group](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/5z9if0/how_to_restore_whatsapp_chats_backed_up_on/) for updates.